# Kernel of linear operator closed if domain non-$T_2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I read on my functional analysis text that the kernel of a linear operator $A:V\to W$ between two topological linear spaces is closed. My book don't require topological linear spaces to be Hausdorff spaces. Without that requirement on $W$, is it possible to prove that $\ker A$ is closed in $V$?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: If the operator is not continuous, there is no reason to expect any topological property from the kernel. If the operator is continuous and the codomain is $T_1$ (hence completely regular, since TVSs satisfy $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$), then the kernel is closed, regardless of whether the domain is $T_1$ or not. If the codomain is not $T_1$, the kernel generally isn't closed even if $A$ is continuous (consider the identity).

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thank you so much!!!